# C# Form Feed/Female sign character '♀' replacement issue

Tags: c#, string, str-replace

Issue identifying the form feed character in c# code when reading a file

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

I have attempted to encode in various formats and then run a replace using UTF-8 hex, UTF-32 hex values for the character.

In the [watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggt75.png) I see
'\f' character

but when i expand out the [visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNfXA.png) i see the actual female character

how do you identify which is the correct character to be searching for? Either the \f or some variation of the female sign?

I have looked at this site for the variations of encoding values with no luck at actually finding it in c#: www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2640/index.htm

Comment: So what are you actually trying to find, the characters `\f`?

Comment: I dont really understand what this is about: You are trying to find the `\f` / `♀` character inside a text?

Comment: Have you tried something like `int pos = contents.IndexOf('\f');` The return value will tell you the first position of the character in the string. Or -1 if there are no occurrences. `string contents = contents.Replace('\f', 'X');` will replace all occurrences of that character with `'X'`.

Comment: Step back a bit. You have to read a text file with the encoding it was saved with. Which encoding is it for your file?

Comment: @Pay - I can't tell which it is rendering as....it would have helped if my attachments showed up, I have re-added the screen shots of what I mean with the rendering of the character.

Comment: @JimMischel - yes I have attempted to search for the character in various ways to know avail. It doesn't find it though it is there.

Comment: @TomBlodget - I do not know what the encoding is. This is coming out of a Mainframe system which after doing some research eludes to the fact that all files coming out of it are ASCII encoded. I did some research on how to attempt to identify file encoding. I utilized edit pad light's encoding feature and it shows the original encoding as Western 1252. I've attempted to read the file in with that encoding `File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));` and locate the character with no luck

Comment: It looks like you should have no problem removing those '\f\r\n' entries from that string

Comment: You know, you could just open the file in a binary editor and find the character you're looking for. That'll tell you if it's actually `\f` or the Unicode equivalent. In Visual Studio, select File->Open->File on the menu, locate the file you want to open, and then click the down-arrow beside the "Open" button. Select "Open with," then scroll to the bottom and select "Binary editor".

Comment: Please provide an example to illustrate the problem. Perhaps a snippet of the file? I wrote a small file that has '\f' ((char)12) characters in it, and `IndexOf` was able to find them just fine. The data read shows '\f' in the Watch window. As far as I can tell, if the character shown in the watch window is `\f`, then `IndexOf('\f')` will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I re-ran everything this morning with the following combination of UTF8 encoding and searching on '\f'

`string contents = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8);
 int pos = contents.IndexOf("\f");`

and finally got a hit.

I still don't know why the watch and visualizer display the character differently, but that combination of searching works.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague on whether you are trying to find the character `\f` or the `♀` character.

If you are trying to find the `♀` character, you can use the hexadecimal code 0x2640, or simply use the character as-is:

```
var ctn = File.ReadAllText("file.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
int pos = ctn.IndexOf((char)0x2640);
int pos1 = ctn.IndexOf('♀');
```

---

Clarification: I think the confusion might come from the fact that character ALT+12 and character ALT+2640 often produces the same 'Female Sign' character, but this is for historical reasons, as the ALT+12 is, in ASCII, a device control code. Only the ALT+2640 Unicode character is specifically designed to always produce the `♀` sign.

Comment: I do apologize for the vagueness of my question. I am not sure whether I should be searching for the '\f' character or the actual 'female sign'. I have updated my original post with screen shots so that you can see that depending on how i look at the string it shows both the '\f' and '♀' characters. I have attempted locating the special character using the following:  (char)0xE2, (char)0x99, (char)0x80, "\u2640", "\f", and now per your suggestion (char)0x2640 and '♀' with no luck

Comment: @J.Romeo It is fine, I was not sure as well, I had to step back and think about the difference between the two. Glad you found your answer!